# defining variables in a blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I'm very new here please.

I'm trying to get some information and pass it to the laravel blade to be displayed on my website. What is for sure is that the call was successful but when I try passing it to the view I get an error that says "undefined variable" in the view page and sometimes the area where information was supposed to be displayed just shows an empty space.

Comment: please elaborate more on the exception

Comment: jason-rpc i think not called successfully  so check address variable empty or not set if set then pass otherwise set default value so find proper problem

Comment: Before returning the `view`, do `dd($address);`... Let's see what you've got.

Comment: remove array in with -> return view('profile.newaddress')->with('address', $address);

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variables in the `view` method instead. The `with` function is for passing individual data, so it doesn't accept an array. Example:

```
return view('profile.newaddress', [
    'address'=>$address
]);
```

If you want to use `with`, try it like this instead (assuming `$address` in a string):

```
return view('profile.newaddress')->with('address', $address);
```

Comment: also note that the variable `address` you use on blade is not this one `$address` in the controller but its the `string key` in the array you sent. The one with ampersand is only used in the Controller, the blade uses the key.... Just in case you use different variable names in the array to send to the blade :D